# Geometric mean of a sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n} = L$$

Proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\ge N$ then $L-\epsilon < a_n < L + \epsilon$.
Now, let $b_n = (a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n} $. We can split this up based on the tail of $\{a_n\}$: $b_n = (a_1\cdots a_{N})^{1/n} (a_{N+1}\cdots a_{n})^{1/n}$. We can bound $(a_{N+1}\cdots a_{n})^{1/n}$ by other sequence which have limits, since we have that $L-\epsilon < a_n < L + \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$: $$(L-\epsilon)^{1-N/n} < (a_{N+1}\cdots a_{n})^{1/n} < (L+\epsilon)^{1-N/n}.$$ Let $C=a_1\cdots a_N$. If we multiply this inequality through by $C^{1/n}$ we find that $$C^{1/n}(L-\epsilon)^{1-N/n} < b_n < C^{1/n}(L+\epsilon)^{1-N/n}.$$ If we take the limit of this inequality, we find that $L - \epsilon \le \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n \le L+\epsilon$. So $L \le \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n \le L$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = L$.

Does this argument work?

Comment: Yes, this argument is fine.

Comment: Take logarithm and use Cesaro sequence.

Comment: @Murthy Why do some proofs of this (and similarly with the proof that the means) converge use the same argument as mine but instead of taking with lim of the inequality, they separately do limsup and liminf, and show that these are equal?

Comment: Don't bother. Your proof is not only correct it as simple as it can be.

Comment: Your argument needs some care when $L=0$ because then $L-\epsilon<0$ and you can't multiply inequalities.

Comment: Well it is not not known in advance that $\lim b_n$ exists and hence the tactical device of $\limsup, \liminf$ is used.

Comment: More precisely if $a_n\leq b_n\leq c_n$ with $a_n\to L, c_n\to M$ then taking limits of the inequality gives us $L\leq\liminf b_n\leq\limsup b_n\leq M$ and you can think of it as  a generalization of squeeze theorem.